# How to handle multiple subdomain with same code base in asp.net core 2.0 API along with Angular 6 app?

Tags: asp.net-core, angular-ui-router, angular6, subdomain, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a web application which is built with angular 6 along with asp.net core API.

My requirement is to use multiple sub-domains for the same code base and validate users and other data based on the sub-domain.

For eg., my original site is www.example.com and subdomains are abc.example.com, def.example.com, xyz.example.com.
If a user registers from def.example.com site, user can only log in to def.example.com sub-domain. If the user tries to log in to abc.example.com or xyz.example.com, we will throw an unauthorized error.

NOTE: We are using the same code base and the same database for all the sub-domains.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have added a route in startup.cs in which I was fetching the sub-domain name using RouteContext.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host. I get proper sub-domain name using this, but I can't pass this sub-domain name to my API.

**Startup.cs**

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.Routes.Add(new SubdomainRoute());

                    routes.MapRoute(
                     name: "default",
                     template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                    routes.MapRoute(
                         "Sitemap",
                         "sitemap.xml",
                         new { controller = "Home", action = "SitemapXml" });

                    routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                      name: "spa-fallback",
                      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
                });
```

SubdomainRoute.cs

```
public class SubdomainRoute : IRouter
{
    public VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(VirtualPathContext context)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public Task RouteAsync(RouteContext routeContext)
    {
        if (routeContext.HttpContext.Request == null || routeContext.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var host = routeContext.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host;
        var index = host.IndexOf(".");
        string[] segments = routeContext.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host.TrimStart('/').Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (index < 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var subdomain = host.Substring(0, index);
        string[] blacklist = { "www", "drivebuyrei", "mail" };

        if (blacklist.Contains(subdomain))
        {
            //return null;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        string controller = (segments.Length > 0) ? segments[0] : "Home";
        string action = (segments.Length > 1) ? segments[1] : "Index";

        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", controller); //Goes to the relevant Controller  class
        routeData.Values.Add("action", action); //Goes to the relevant action method on the specified Controller
        routeData.Values.Add("subdomain", subdomain); //pass subdomain as argument to action method

        routeContext.RouteData = routeData;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```